# Nginx proxy_pass cannot load asset

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm configuring nginx with this config:

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

It works, but without all assets. I inspect element, the assets redirect to http://127.0.0.1:10000 (absolutely 404), where it should be http://127.0.0.1:10000/test/asset.css.

Need advice :)

PS: My server is using angular2 (npm start)

Comment: How did you solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May the force be with you:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
    root /root/of/your/public/assets;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

Comment: if i have another website, is it not conflict?

Comment: Just create server block, put it inside the server block configuration.

Comment: [A different solution.](https://serverfault.com/a/932636/310942)